# Canon camera DIY repair

Tags: canon, autofocus, repair

I have a digital rebel XT, an 18-55mm, and 75-300mm lens, all by Canon. Everything has saltwater damage. I'm aware that it's cheaper to just replace it all, but I was fiddling around with it, testing the individual components, and I couldn't get anything to fail except the camera as a whole. Even the sensor has no signs of corrosion. 
I tested the focus motor on the 75-300, and it works. After assembling the lens, I tried it on a working camera and the lens works great! Where can I find replacement parts for the camera (screws, wires)?

Answer (score 2):

**Ebay.** Used Rebel XT's can be found on Ebay for $40-60. I spotted one "for parts only" that's currently at about $10.